# Program to divide the array into N continuous subarray so that the sum of each subarray is odd

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

The problem gives two inputs : The array(arr) and the times the number of subarrays to be made out of it(n). The sum of the subarrays should be odd

It is already clear that if all the numbers are even. The odd sum subarray is not possible. For an odd sum , the continuous 2 numbers should be either odd+even or even+odd . But I can't seem to break them into N subarrays. Please Help with the logic.

I can be completely wrong with the logic. I just can't seem to get the hang of it.

Comment: Divide the array after the first _n_ − 1 odd numbers, then test whether the last subarray sums up to an odd number. For example, for _n_ = 3, the array { 1 | 2 3 | 5 7 9 } can be divides; { 1 | 2 4 6 } has too few odd numbers and { 1 | 3 | 5 7 }'s last subarray has an even sum and no rearrangement of the split can change that. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from the first element of the array. Use a variable `cur_sum` to keep track of the current sum. Iterate the array till the `cur_sum` becomes odd, that becomes the first subarray. Then make `cur_sum = 0` and start iterating the remaining array. Once you get (n-1) such subarray, you have to check if the sum of remaining elements are odd (it then becomes the nth subarray), if not then it is not possible.

Comment: Exactly. The last subarray is a 50-50 chance game. The sum can be either even or odd. Isn't there something that can effectively reduce that. Thank you for the answer though.

Comment: If you just want to know if it is possible or not. Then count the number of odd numbers, let it be `oddCount`, and let `x = oddCount - (n-1)'. if 'x > 0' and `x` is odd, then it is possible, otherwise not.